# Ubuntu updating 13.04. Missing sidebar as well as header bar and mini, maxi and exit button

Tags: upgrade, updates, 13.04

I've upgrade my Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04. I dunno what happend while updating, but I've lost the Launcher bar and header bar. and when I opened the Terminal I've not seen the three buttons ( mini, max and exit ).

Answer (score 2):

Seems your Unity interface is broken. Are you using any proprietary drivers? NVIDIA/ATI etc? Those seem to have a spitefull history with X and Unity...Anyways, try running the below:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Comment: It works!!, wonderful. Thank you Kindly, Charlie. But When I opened my Laptop to check the answer, the desktop background was white. :( what do you think bro ?

Comment: Am not sure I get what you mean by "When I opened my Laptop to check the answer, the desktop background was white". Is the unity launcher and icons displayed correctly but disappear when you open your web browser?

Comment: Also, please **vote up** the answer you like.